# Responsive columns, prevent children from getting moved between columns when collapsed

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid, column-count

I have a responsive column-count grid (3 on desktop, 2 on tablet, 1 on mobile) and when you unfold / collapse a children, everything gets moved between the columns. I also want to keep the order:

[image]

How can I prevent this? Maybe there's a `flexbox` solution?

Example:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  ul {
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 1;
    column-gap: 20px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 360px) {
  ul {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 20px;
  }
}

ul li {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 1 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 2 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 3 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 4 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 5 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 6 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 7 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 8 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 9 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 10 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 11 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I played around with `flexbox` and `grid` but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: You can not rely on any mechanism that automatically divides the elements into columns based on their height, if you want to then _change_ that height for individual elements, but expect the distribution across columns to stay the same. So you need to start with something that has the items separated into two different container elements to begin with, or something like that.

Comment: @CBroe thank you, I thought there might exist a CSS solution for this I'm not aware of.

Comment: It seems that you used imgur link. Instead use stackoverflow's image upload, otherwise imgur clears unused images.

Comment: @nurgasemetey thanks I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the columns responsive without any media queries just using `display: flex;` together with `flex-wrap: wrap;` which will automatically wrap them depending on available space. Placing the list items into their own columns also guarantees they won't re-flow between columns (the default behavior of `column-count` which it sounds like you want to avoid). Example:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: -20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container > * {
  margin-right: 20px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ul>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 1 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 2 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 3 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 4 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 5 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 6 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 7 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 8 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 9 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><span class="collapsible">Item 10 (click to unfold)</span>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thank you, works really good, but by splitting it into own lists (3 lists) you can't achieve this ordering: https://i.imgur.com/s8ertJR.png